# How to fret an F# root note with a drop-E capo?

Tags: guitar, capos

I commonly play with a five-string capo on the second fret of the guitar, leaving the E string open. This only becomes a problem when attempting to play an F# chord with the bass note:

[image]

As you can see, it's hard to get my thumb in there to fret that F# bass note, particularly on this narrow neck. (It's easier on my dreadnought guitar.)

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps there are better capos for this purpose? Is my technique off? Should I get started on growing that third hand?

Comment: It would have been nice with sort of a button you could press with your thumb that fretted the F#! :-)

Comment: @UlfÅkerstedt A capo with that would actually be really cool.

Comment: @MatthewRead: The thing I'm surprised nobody has produced yet would be a guitar with a two-fret sixth-string extension, somewhat like the C/E string extensions on upright basses, so that pushing a button would make the sixth string play a D rather than an E, thus allowing a non-wimpy D chord.

Comment: @supercat Lever tuning machines are a thing, but they're expensive.

Comment: @neilfein: Lever-tuning machines change the string tension.  I was thinking of a guitar which combined a five-string nut with a fret at the corresponding spot on the sixth string, so the lever would change the *unfretted length* of the sixth string rather than the tension.

Comment: @supercat Why not get a baritone guitar and just capo it up as needed?

Comment: @neilfein: One could drop-tune all six strings on a longer guitar and then use a five-string capo on the second fret, but that would mean the marker dots would be in the wrong places.  Further, I was envisioning something which would fret the low string at E except when a key/button is pushed, so the guitar could be played perfectly normally except that adjusting the D string fingering to hit the special key would allow a non-wimpy six-string D chord.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have room to back your capo off from the low E slightly, which could help your thumb fit in.  Beyond that, try turning your thumb in towards the guitar a bit and extending it straight up, then pulling it down against the edge of the neck so that the fleshy bit sticks over the edge and pulls the string down to the fretboard.  Doesn't work for everyone, but worth a try.

Comment: That's exactly what I do on my dreadnought - angle my thumb in there. But on this guitar, I really don't have the room for this.

Comment: And, unfortunately, this is about as far as I can back the capo off the frets and still have it hold the notes down well. But perhaps I could cut the end in a bit with a hacksaw and angle it. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to play it as you would for a barre chord, but just use your first finger for that root note, leaving your other three fingers to play the notes you currently play with your first, second and third fingers.

It will be easier than a full barre, and it removes the awkward thumb angle entirely.